# Hybrid RSA-AES encryption

Tags: java, encryption, aes, rsa, hybrid

i try to create hybrid encryption using RSA-AES but for now i face a problem in this coding. From this code i try to Creating an RSA key pair , private and public key. After that i should Generating a random key symmetrical algorithm AES then i have to create an AES cipher in order to encrypt a text string with the AES key. Then after  the text is encrypted with the AES key, then the AES key needs to be encrypted with the RSA public key and the encrypted AES key needs to be decrypted with the RSA private key. And finally decrypt the text message entered with AES key in order to read the message. I think i missing something in my coding. Please help me guys.

```
    import java.math.BigInteger;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.security.KeyFactory;
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.PrivateKey;
    import java.security.PublicKey;
    import java.security.SecureRandom;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
    import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
    import java.util.logging.Level;
    import java.util.logging.Logger;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

    import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

    import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
    import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

    public class HybridAesRsa 
    {

        private  Cipher cipher;

        // RSA keys will be generated when the client and server connect
        private PrivateKey myPrivateKey;
        private byte[] myPublicKey;
        private byte[] interlocutorPublicKey = null;

        // Strings are encoded / decoded in BASE64
        private BASE64Decoder b64decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        private BASE64Encoder b64encoder = new BASE64Encoder();

        public HybridAesRsa()
        {
        try
        {   
        cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
        } 

        catch (Exception ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(HybridAesRsa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
        } 
        }

    // Generate the pair of public and private keys using 1024 bytes
    public KeyPair generateKey() throws Exception
    {
       KeyPair keyPair = null;

       try{
        //generate RSA key pair
        KeyPairGenerator rsaKeyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        rsaKeyGen.initialize(1024);
        keyPair = rsaKeyGen.generateKeyPair();

        //RSA public and private key
        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        //System.out.println("RSA public key 1 ---> "+publicKey);
        //System.out.println("RSA private key 1 ---> " +privateKey);

        //for Chatting
        myPublicKey = publicKey.getEncoded();
        setMyPrivateKey(privateKey);

        //Generating a random key symmetrical algorithm AES
        KeyGenerator aesKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
        SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom(); 
        aesKeyGenerator.init(random);           
        SecretKey aesSecretKey = aesKeyGenerator.generateKey();

        /*//The key is presented in a byte array           
        byte[] symmetricKey = aesSecretKey.getEncoded(); 

        //Printing out the generated key       
        System.out.println("\nAES symmetric key --> " + symmetricKey); */       

      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(HybridAesRsa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
    }
    return keyPair;
    }

    // Encrypts text using public key
    public String encrypt(String text, PublicKey publicKey, SecretKey aesSecretKey ) throws Exception 
{   
    //Creating an AES cipher in order to encrypt a text string with the AES key 
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey);

    //Now that the text is encrypted with the AES key, then the AES key needs to be encrypted with the RSA public key
    Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);

    byte[] encryptedAESkey = rsaCipher.doFinal(aesSecretKey.getEncoded()); 

    //Printing out the encrypted AES key
    System.out.println("\nAES key encrypted with RSA --> " + encryptedAESkey);

    return text;
}

// Use the public key to encrypt the interlocutor
public String encrypt(String text) throws Exception 
{
    return encrypt(text, bytesToPublicKey(interlocutorPublicKey), null);
}

// Decrypts text using private key
public String decrypt(String text, PrivateKey privatekey) throws Exception 
{
    // Now the encrypted AES key needs to be decrypted with the RSA private key 
    Cipher rsaCipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    rsaCipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privatekey);
    byte[] encryptedAESkey = null;
    byte[] decryptedAESkey = rsaCipher2.doFinal(encryptedAESkey);

    //Print out the decrypted AES key
    System.out.println("AES key decrypted with RSA private key --> " + decryptedAESkey);

    //And finally decrypt the text message entered with AES key in order to read the message. 
    Cipher aesCipher2 = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 

    Key aesSecretKey = null;
    aesCipher2.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,aesSecretKey);

    byte[] encrypt = null;
    byte [] decrypt = aesCipher2.doFinal(encrypt);

    return text;

}

// Use my private key to decrypt
public String decrypt(String text) throws Exception 
{
    return decrypt(text, myPrivateKey);
}

// Public Key the caller is sent in byte [ ] and converted into a PublicKey object
public static PublicKey bytesToPublicKey(byte[] publicKeybytes)
{
    PublicKey publicKey = null;

    try {
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(publicKeybytes);
        publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    } 

    catch (InvalidKeySpecException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HybridAesRsa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } 

    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex){
        Logger.getLogger(HybridAesRsa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

        return publicKey;    
}

    // Test
public static void main(String[] args){
    try {
        HybridAesRsa crypto = new HybridAesRsa();
        KeyPair keyPair = crypto.generateKey();

        PublicKey publicKey = keyPair.getPublic();
        PrivateKey privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
        KeyGenerator aesKeyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES"); 
        SecretKey aesSecretKey = aesKeyGenerator.generateKey();          

        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = privateKey.getEncoded();
        byte[] symmetricKey = aesSecretKey.getEncoded(); 

        System.out.println("RSA Public key: " + new BigInteger(publicKeyBytes));
        System.out.println("RSA Private key: " + new BigInteger(privateKeyBytes));
        System.out.println("AES symmetric key --> " + new BigInteger(symmetricKey));

        Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
        aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, aesSecretKey);

        String testeMsg = "As a seed knows how to make a flower ? I love you.";
        byte[] encrypt = aesCipher.doFinal(testeMsg.getBytes());

        Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedAESkey = rsaCipher.doFinal(aesSecretKey.getEncoded()); 


        String encrypted = crypto.encrypt(testeMsg, bytesToPublicKey(publicKeyBytes), aesSecretKey);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text: " + encrypted);

        String decrypted = crypto.decrypt(encrypted, keyPair.getPrivate());                    
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text: " + decrypted);
    }  

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            Logger.getLogger(HybridAesRsa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

}

 public byte[] getMyPublicKey(){
     return myPublicKey;
}

public void setMyPublicKey(byte[] myPublicKey) {
    this.myPublicKey = myPublicKey;
}

public PrivateKey getMyPrivateKey(){
    return myPrivateKey;
}

public byte[] getInterlocutorPublicKey(){
     return interlocutorPublicKey;
}

public boolean hasInterlocutorPublicKey(){
    return interlocutorPublicKey!=null;
}

public void setInterlocutorPublicKey(byte[] interlocutorPublicKey){
    this.interlocutorPublicKey = interlocutorPublicKey;
}

public void setMyPrivateKey(PrivateKey aMyPrivateKey){
    myPrivateKey = aMyPrivateKey;
}
}
```

Here the error for this code

```
    Jun 19, 2016 5:50:14 PM HybridAesRsa main
    SEVERE: null
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
    at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2117)
    at HybridAesRsa.decrypt(HybridAesRsa.java:125)
    at HybridAesRsa.main(HybridAesRsa.java:204)
```

Comment: [OT] Interesting to see how one codes RSA in Java where one has to use "BigInteger" at lots of places. In PLs like Python, operatons with huge integers are just like with small ones, thus being more convenient for the programmers. (cf. my RSA code  s13.zetaboards.com/Crypto/topic/7234475/1/)

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("RSA");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. Nowadays, you should use OAEP instead of the default PKCS#1 v1.5 padding. So you should probably use `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/OAEPWithSHA-256AndMGF1Padding");`

Comment: General advice: **Always use a fully qualified Cipher string.** `Cipher.getInstance("AES");` may result in different ciphers depending on the default security provider. It most likely results in `"AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding"`, but it doesn't have to be. If it changes, you'll lose compatibility between different JVMs.

Comment: **Never use [ECB mode](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/14487/13022)**. It's deterministic and therefore not semantically secure. You should at the very least use a randomized mode like [CBC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/22260/13022) or [CTR](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/2378/13022). It is better to authenticate your ciphertexts so that attacks like a [padding oracle attack](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18185/13022) are not possible. This can be done with authenticated modes like GCM or EAX, or with an [encrypt-then-MAC](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme.

Answer (score -1):

You have this code:

```
byte[] encrypt = null;
byte [] decrypt = aesCipher2.doFinal(encrypt);
```

where you try to encrypt with a buffer that's initialised to null .. that is not possible.

The exception is quite clear:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Null input buffer
```